# How to center text in merged cell?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tex-core

I have this table and I want to have the text from merged cell in the middle of it, I marked the place where I want it. How can I do that?

```tex
\begin{table}[h]
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|}}
\hline
ICANN & \multirow{2}{=}{\centering Europe Reseaux IP Europeens Network Coordination Centre} & NASK \\
\hhline{-~-}
The Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers & & Naukowa i Akademicka Sieć Komputerowa \\
\hline
Świat & Europa & Polska \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Instytucje zarządzające adresami IP oraz nadzorujące działanie serwerów DNS}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table]

Comment: `\multirow{4.25}{=}` instead of `\multirow{2}{=}` should get you closer the the expected output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Yeah, in this example it works for me, but I believe there is better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `nicematrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.33333\arrayrulewidth}}}[hvlines]
ICANN & \Block{2-1}{Europe Reseaux IP\\ Europeens Network\\ Coordination Centre} & NASK \\
The Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers & & Naukowa i Akademicka Sieć Komputerowa \\
Świat & Europa & Polska \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Instytucje zarządzające adresami IP oraz nadzorujące działanie serwerów DNS}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dang, is there _anything_ that `nicematrix`can't do? :D

Comment: Compile only once :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which (a) uses a `tabularx` environment, so you don't have to calculate the column widths and (b) employs an `m` column type to center the cell contents vertically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hhline,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | *{3}{C|} }
\hline
ICANN &  & NASK \\
\hhline{-~-}
The Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers & 
Europe Reseaux IP Europeens Network Coordination Centre & 
Naukowa i Akademicka Sieć Komputerowa \\
\hline
Świat & Europa & Polska \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Instytucje zarządzające adresami IP oraz nadzorujące działanie serwerów DNS}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Since there's the acronym "RIPE" for "Réseaux IP Européens", you could arrange the tabular material more symmetrically as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | *{3}{C|} }
\hline
ICANN & RIPE & NASK \\
\hline
Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers & 
Réseaux IP Européens Network Coordination Centre & 
Naukowa i Akademicka Sieć Komputerowa \\
\hline
Świat & Europa & Polska \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Instytucje zarządzające adresami IP oraz nadzorujące działanie serwerów DNS}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the `multirow` documentation (see the remarks on page 7 in `multirow.pdf`), this uses the `vmove` argument to lower the text by some amount to roughly center it vertically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|}}
\hline
ICANN & \multirow{2}{=}[-20pt]{\centering Europe Reseaux IP Europeens Network Coordination Centre} & NASK \\
\hhline{-~-}
The Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers & & Naukowa i Akademicka Sieć Komputerowa \\
\hline
Świat & Europa & Polska \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Instytucje zarządzające adresami IP oraz nadzorujące działanie serwerów DNS}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]